# How to install camel-osgi in apache-karaf-4.0.4

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf

I tried to installed camel-osgi using below command. It given an error.

```
karaf@root()>feature:install camel-osgi
```

Error:

> Error executing command: No matching features for camel-osgi/0.0.0

Comment: Just install `camel`. There is no `camel-osgi` feature

Comment: `camel-osgi` is a very old artifact that has been discontinued years ago. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to install the feature repository of camel before using any camel feature.

```
feature:repo-add camel 2.16.2
feature:install camel-core
```

Karaf can also show you the available features using `feature:list`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But using these commands camel-osgi not installed. Need to install camel-osgi as a feature.

Comment: camel-osgi does NOT exists. Explain better why you think you need to install that.

Comment: According to the [http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-osgi-camel-part1.html] , we need camel-osgi to proceed the testing. How to test the service and camel budles worrking process?

Comment: I think the tutorial is simply outdated. We should update it. You can take a look at my camel tutorial. http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2012/01/03/Karaf+Tutorial+Part+5+-+Running+Apache+Camel+integrations+in+OSGi

Comment: Yes, it may say so on that tutorial but it also says further down that the tutorial is out of date and is based on camel 2.0. You don't need to follow it. Just follow Christian's instructions.

Comment: Thank you Christian and Souciance. Christian unfortunately that link is not working.. it gives 'Service Temporarily Unavailable'.. Could you please provide a working url.

Comment: The links is fine ... my website was down. Now it should work again.